# Select rows whose values in one column match specfic vector

Tags: matlab, indexing

First my question seemed easy, but i still can't find relevant answer to it.
So I have matrix with size of mx4

```
a = [(2:6)' rand(5,3)]
a  =     
2.    0.1589990    0.2725595    0.2944531  
3.    0.0181815    0.3437655    0.5718074  
4.    0.4098371    0.2033702    0.2141770  
5.    0.0105835    0.3011945    0.6895462  
6.    0.1965310    0.2762596    0.5855573
```

And vector b with size of mx1. Elements of b always can be find in the first column of a. For example:

```
b = [2;3;6]
```

What I want is to select rows whose value in first column matches values of b, i.e.

```
ans  = 
2.    0.1589990    0.2725595    0.2944531  
3.    0.0181815    0.3437655    0.5718074  
6.    0.1965310    0.2762596    0.5855573
```

All I've come with so far are these solutions:

```
Ans(1,:) = a(a(:,1)==b(1),:);
Ans(2,:) = a(a(:,1)==b(2),:);
Ans(3,:) = a(a(:,1)==b(3),:);
```

And slightly automatized version:

```
Ans = zeros(size(b,1),size(a,2));
for i = 1:size(b,1)
    Ans(i,:)=a(a(:,1)==b(i),:)
end
```

Is there any possibility to make it easy, may be in one line or without loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This -

```
out = a(find(sum(squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,a,permute(b,[3 2 1])),2)),2)),:)
```

Wow, that's a huge thing isn't it!

Slightly shorter -

```
out = a(any(squeeze(bsxfun(@eq,a(:,1),permute(b,[3 2 1]))),2),:)
```

And shorterer -

```
out = a(any(bsxfun(@eq,a(:,1),b'),2),:)
```

Without `bsxfun` or `ismember`? Hmm..try out `intersect`, that is basically similar to `ismember` -

```
[~,ind,~]  = intersect(a(:,1),b);
out = a(ind,:)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) is your friend here:

```
a = [(2:6)' rand(5,3)]
b = [2;3;6]

a(ismember(a(:,1),b),:)
a =   
   2.000000   0.065121   0.172047   0.490842
   3.000000   0.585701   0.650922   0.260139
   4.000000   0.266305   0.543419   0.562515
   5.000000   0.760789   0.378180   0.560597
   6.000000   0.058769   0.926874   0.538872

b =   
   2
   3
   6

ans =    
   2.000000   0.065121   0.172047   0.490842
   3.000000   0.585701   0.650922   0.260139
   6.000000   0.058769   0.926874   0.538872
```

<sub>Thanks to RTL for noting that `a(ismember(a,b),:)` might match elements that were not in the first column.</sub>